# python diff instance method

Tags: python, instance

I find the following confusing:

```
class B(object):
    def a(self):
            print 'love', id(lambda x: x)


b = B()
b1 = B()
print id(b.a)
print id(b1.a)
```

The result is the same.

Comment: As you didn't assign `b.a` anywhere it was garbage collected and Python re-used the same memory location for `b1.a`. Check the `instance methods` section in the [datamodel page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) to learn how they are created.

Comment: wow, thanks very much!